# Apache HttpClient 3, multi threaded with different credential for each request

Tags: java, authentication, httpclient, connection-pooling

I am using **HttpClient 3** with **MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager**

If I connect to a site with valid credentials
and then connect again with invalid credentials, the second connection surprisingly works. I am assuming this is because the connection manager uses a pooled connection and does not reauthenticate the already authenticated hosts.
However I want HttpClient to fail if I provide invalid credetials, how can I do that?

Tthis is part of how I use `HttpClient`:

```
//run on each call
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(getMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManagerSingleton());


....
 httpClient.getState().setCredentials(
                authscope,
                new NTCredentials(
                        ntlmCredentials.getUsername(),//here i give wrong creds on the second attempt
                        ntlmCredentials.getPassword(),
                        localHostName, ntlmCredentials.getDomain()));
```

Comment: Are you passing credentials as Basic-Auth ?

Comment: I am using NTLM, i pass the credentials each request, but the MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager is a singleton .